# How to change zero rows returned with a custom value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query :

```
select top 1 FinishDate from Sk_RizeTamdidEshterak where CodeRizeSanad=72150
```

and the result is :

[image]

It's returned zero rows and if that happens, I want to show some default text, not nothing.

Comment: use    isnull(finishdate,'Default')

Comment: @Kavin. Are you sure? Did you test this? Do a little test and see what you get when no rows are returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from Sk_RizeTamdidEshterak where CodeRizeSanad=72150)
  SELECT 'Default text' AS FinishDate
ELSE  
  SELECT top 1 FinishDate from Sk_RizeTamdidEshterak where CodeRizeSanad=72150
```

Note that if there is no FinishDate and "Default text" is returned it will be a VARCHAR otherwise you get a DATETIME. Depending on your front end you will need to consider that two different DATATYPEs may be returned!